# Bootstrap 3 making fixed column fill its width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I am using BS3 and need to have 2 columns with column 1 sticky whilst the second scrolls as normal - this works fine using class affix on the 1st column but that column never fills the full width hence it doesn't have the correct borders, background etc as the rest of the content.

I have read a few answers which explain this is because fixed takes the content out of the normal flow of the page - some suggestions have been to use width: inherit and I have tried a few JS options I found in various answers but none work for me. Likewise making column 1, 100% makes it full the whole area and clash with the 2nd column

Is there a simple way in BS3 of having a fixed left column with a normal right column where both columns fill to their full width?

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="panel panel-flat affix">
              <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:red">
          1 of 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="panel panel-flat">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ornare ipsum vitae 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
  }

  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6bwkzd5y/1/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Affix uses `position: fixed` to display a block statically, and fixed positioned elements don't listen to the parents positional styles to display. To make this work, I added a custom class `inherit-width` and the style `width: inherit`. Optionally, if you want to make all `.affix` elements have this, you can just do that with some simple CSS: `.affix { width: inherit; }`.

Here is the updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dx70wv95/2/